# JavaScript user defined template literal formatting from object

Tags: javascript, typescript, template-literals

I'd like to allow a user to define a template which is interpolated from an object. For example, I have the object:

```js
const desc = {
    reagent: 'NaOH',
    mass: '25.6g',
};
```

I'd like the user to be able to define their own format string, such as `'${mass} of ${reagent}'`, such that I can call some `format(formatStr, desc)` to obtain `'25.6g of NaOH'`.

Is this type of behavior built in?

Comment: I don't think this is possible out-of-the-box. You probably need to take in the user defined template literal and perform replacements with the appropriate values. It should be pretty straightforward if you extract the template names

Comment: yup key/value pairs swao keys with value in string with string replace of ${<key>} of value

Comment: Look at [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates), part of the template literal addition to ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a well-known utility library, then [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) has a pretty comprehensive template engine built into it.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template

Taken from their documentation:

```
// Use the "interpolate" delimiter to create a compiled template.
var compiled = _.template('hello <%= user %>!');
compiled({ 'user': 'fred' });

// => 'hello fred!'

// Use the ES template literal delimiter as an "interpolate" delimiter.
var compiled = _.template('hello ${ user }!');
compiled({ 'user': 'pebbles' });

// => 'hello pebbles!'
```

You can also specify your own *custom delimiter*:

```
// Use custom template delimiters.
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g;
var compiled = _.template('hello {{ user }}!');
compiled({ 'user': 'mustache' });

// => 'hello mustache!'
```

If bundle size is a concern you can opt to only install the `template` method from Lodash:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.template

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's just insert field XY and no computation in there, it's fairly simple to build:

```js
const desc = {
    reagent: 'NaOH',
    mass: '25.6g',
};

const formatStr = '${mass} of ${reagent}';

function format(tpl, args){
  return tpl.replace(/\$\{[^\}]+\}/g, (m) => args[m.slice(2, -1).trim()]);
}

console.log(format(formatStr, desc));
```

if you want to parse these placeholder and do computation in there, we're moving into the realm of [evil()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-javascripts-eval-evil/).